# Nodewebkit app takes time to load in windows

Tags: windows, node.js, packaging, node-webkit, software-distribution

Newbie to `NodeWebKit` and facing some issues with packaging.
I have created a .nw file and then .exe file by following steps defined in [Package and Distribute Node webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/How-to-package-and-distribute-your-apps)

Problem I am facing currently is that Node webkit takes say 2-3 minutes to load application.

Is there any idea why is it taking so much time?
If it takes more time than can I do something to run that faster?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially executable file which was created was 92mb. While creating a nw file, I was adding unnecessary files as showin figure[image]

Some of folders which are selected contain big files like `node_modules` which is 126mb (In my case)
Because of this, Once file was completely packaged and run on different machines, It was taking time to load due to extraction of compressed file in windows which was approximately two minutes.

Solution was to select only required folders for packaging and eliminate others as shown in image below:
[image]

And also to minimise size of application, If any of files were big from selected files, I minified them before packaging.

In this way, instead of getting a 95mb compressed file, I got 1mb file which I packaged and ran it and it took only 5 seconds to load application instead of 2 minutes.